# List of strings to list of chars - [[Char]] to [Char] haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to convert list like this `["a","b","c"]` to this `['a','b','c']`. The thing is i used

```
splitOn
```

function which gave me `[[Char]]` from `[Char]`. Is there a way to convert this list of string to list of char? Assuming strings are length of 1 of course.

Comment: What do you want to do if any of the strings aren't length 1?

Comment: It will not happen, because of my exact input to splitOn

Comment: You might also want to use [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5BChar%5D%5D+-%3E+%5BChar%5D) for those kind of questions. Given signatures it usually spits out some useful pointers.

Comment: I tried it, only thing with this signatures found was `unlines` and `unwords`. Which does not work for me. But thanks for your point.

Comment: @nocturne `concat` is the fourth result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [**`concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat):

```
Prelude> concat ["a","b","c"]
"abc"
```

Since a `String` is a type alias for `[Char]`, so `"abc"` is short for `['a', 'b', 'c']`:

```
Prelude> concat ["a","b","c"] == ['a', 'b', 'c']
True
```

Comment: It worked thanks! I will mark this as right answer later.

Answer (score 4):

`concat ["a", "b", "c"]` will give you the string `"abc"` which is the same as `['a', 'b', 'c']`